# how to create unique id for each user in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, sql

how to create unique id for each user in asp.net C#

I was used random number for each profile but its not unique.

Comment: Why not leave that to an Identity field in the database?

Comment: u mean to say autonumber?

Comment: Yes, depending on the RDBMS you could say autonumber X-)

Comment: okk but i want to create id like suposse personname is shaikh and city is pune,state is maharashtra, country is india then combination of all this field like INMHPU123333......?

Answer (score 3):

[Guid.NewGuid()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) is almost unique.

### Usage:

```
Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

// Output: e62e2706-a8db-4fae-891a-65985fd80351
```

Comment: How to use this method..could u please tel me

Comment: I updated the answer. If you want string value, you can use `id.ToString();`. C# Guid is equivalent to SQL uniqueidentifier.

Comment: Well, at some point, you might get duplicate, but chances are zero to none. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1705517/296861).

Comment: okk but i want to create id like suposse personname is shaikh and city is pune,state is maharashtra, country is india then combination of all this field like INMHPU123333.

Comment: Sounds more like you want a hashing function. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454004/calculate-a-md5-hash-from-a-string

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using SQL Server (I’m pretty sure something similar exists in Oracle and MySQL but I can’t confirm) you can use [identity column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) with integer value that will automatically generate unique ID for new user.

If you need something different like you shown in one of the comments “INMHPU123333” then you’ll need to create a separate function for this.

Note that this is not really ideal from the performance perspective because it will cause big index fragmentation. Not a huge deal though if you don’t have large number of records.