# Converting toHexString and MessageDigest in Java to c# equivalent

Tags: java, c#, integer, message-digest

I have problem converting the following Java code into toHexString and MessageDigest equivalent to C#.net code. I spend much time in converting them, but seems the result can never be the same.

Please help me especially in toHexString part.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String keyString = "01100880200013048720181107174008PC".toString();
        MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md5.update(keyString.getBytes("utf-8"));

        byte[] temp = md5.digest("".getBytes("utf-8"));

        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; ++i) {
            result = result + Integer.toHexString(0xFF & temp[i] | 0xFFFFFF00).substring(6);
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate a MD5 hash from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454004/calculate-a-md5-hash-from-a-string)

Comment: If interested to convert byte array to hexadecimal, here's a good topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 1):

You can get the hexadecimal `string` representation of an `int` by calling the `.ToString("X2")` method on it. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#XFormatString) is the documentation for more options.

To get the first 6 chars you can call the `.SubString(0, 6)` on the hex value.