# DotNet Core - Cryptography hash functions returning inconsistent results

Tags: c#, hash, .net-core, md5

I have a very simple function in my .Net Core (v2.x) application that computes a hash of a string. The code is as follows:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public static string CalculateMd5Hash(string input)
{
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        var inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

        var hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

        return BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    }
}
```

I also have written a pretty simple test for it and it seems to work on my windows machine. It matches the expected output from [this online hash calculator](http://onlinemd5.com/):

```
public void CalculateMd5Hash_CalculatesHashCorrectly()
{
    var hash = HashingUtility.CalculateMd5Hash("CreateMD5Hash_123_!£$%^&*");

    Assert.Equal("9a3e6e29cc3d1eae7d7a0df0a24a1deb", hash);
}
```

The problem is that this test fails in our CI pipeline, which runs in a linux machine, but I kinda feel that it should not make any difference, as UTF-8 and hexadecimal strings are both platform independent concepts.

```
Expected: 9a3e6e29cc3d1eae7d7a0df0a24a1deb
Actual:   fb5f4b930ea2b600c6b976b954a56189
```

Any ideas, what is going on here?

EDIT: I tried what @DavidG had suggested, but without any luck, exactly the same output. Here is the updated version of the hash function:

```
public static string CalculateMd5Hash(string input)
{
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        var inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

        var hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes .Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hashBytes [i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString().ToLower();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably because BitConverter is 'endian' - _"The order of bytes in the array returned by the GetBytes method overloads (as well as the order of bits in the integer returned by the DoubleToInt64Bits method **and the order of hexadecimal strings returned by the ToString(Byte[]) method)** depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or big-endian."_

Comment: Probably something to do with `BitConverter`, have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24031467/1663001) instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate a MD5 hash from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454004/calculate-a-md5-hash-from-a-string)

Comment: @DavidG, I tried your method, but still without any luck

Comment: How about [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55490468/1663001)?

Comment: Where is your input actually coming from? Do you get identical results if the string is `"Hello, world!"` or `"CreateMD5Hash_123_!\u00a3$%^&*"`? Notably, your string contains `£`, which is the only character that is not in ASCII and is thus subject to potential encoding differences -- not when converted to UTF-8, but when parsed in source by the compiler or read from an external file.

Comment: Git is also a rich source of problems when it comes to character set conversion issues, so if your CI pipeline pulls the source from it for compilation I'd take a good look at that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, you were right, it's the non-ascii character and git is a likely culprit. I asked a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56955494/git-messes-up-with-non-ascii-characters-on-linux-container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JeroenMostert suggested in comments, it seems that the non-ascii character `£` is lost after the `git clone`, therefore this has nothing to do (as I hoped) with the C# code, UTF-8, or hash functions.

I asked a separate question regarding this here: [Git messes up with non-ascii characters on Linux container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56955494/git-messes-up-with-non-ascii-characters-on-linux-container)