# Git messes up with non-ascii characters on Linux container

Tags: linux, git, character-encoding

I have a .Net Core (C#) project with the following line in one of the classes:

`var input = "£";`

But when I do a git clone in a Docker container (`microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk`) it messes it up and displays it as `�` (in `bash` using `cat`).

And when I run it, its `Utf-8` bytes are `[239, 191, 189] = [EF, BF, BD]` which seem to be a so-called [Unicode replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character).

Windows editor that I use is VS 2017, but character is displayed properly on other windows machines and parsed properly by `dotnet run/test` command, so I don't think this is a problem of failing to save the character incorrectly.

Any ideas why I am seeing such a mess and how to solve it?

**Some details**

- I get bytes using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("£");`
- It works perfectly well on `Windows 10` machine
- Linux version `Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)` from the `cat /etc/os-release`
- `locale -a` returns `C` `C.UTF-8` `POSIX`
- On Windows Notepad++, when opened, is claims to be ANSI and is displayed correctly.

Running `fgrep 'var input' file.cs | od -tx1 -c`

```
0000100  76  61  72  20  69  6e  70  75  74  20  3d  20  22  a3  22  3b
          v   a   r       i   n   p   u   t       =       " 243   "   ;
```

Comment: Which character encoding do you use in your editor (or IDE project) on Windows? Which locale do you use on Linux?

Comment: ...and what is your global and project's Git configuration file / settings. Do you use any Git hooks?

Comment: @Bodo The editor on Windows is Visual Studio. But it works fine when cloned on another windows laptop, therefore I don't think the problem is on windows end

Comment: @bodo `locale -a` displays `C C.UTF-8 POSIX`

Comment: @eddyP23 Please [edit] your question to add **all** requested information instead of answering in comments. Probably Windows and Linux use different encoding. On Linux, please run `fgrep 'var input' yourfile|od -tx1 -c`. On Windows you can try to find out the file's encoding when you open it in Notepad++. Is the character shown correct in Notepad++? What is selected in the "Encoding" menu? If the character is not displayed correct, try other encodings.

Comment: updated the question @Bodo

Comment: Your file contains a single byte `a3` which corresponds to the Windows-1252 encoding. Your Linux system displays `�` because it is not a valid UTF-8 encoding. Maybe you can configure Visual Studio to use UTF-8 instead of Windows-1252.

Comment: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: Thanks @Bodo. I am happy to accept your help as an answer if you write one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file contains a single byte `a3` which corresponds to the Windows-1252 encoding for the character `£`. Your Linux system displays `�` because it is not a valid UTF-8 encoding.

You should configure Visual Studio to use UTF-8 instead of Windows-1252.