# How to implement Apache Shiro MD5Hash in C#

Tags: java, c#, shiro

What's the equivalent C# code of following Java code:

```
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.Md5Hash;
public static String enPwd(String username, String pwd) { return (new Md5Hash(username + pwd, username, 2)).toHex().toString(); }
```

I want to know how to get same hash result in C#.

Comment: tried, but not get same result

Comment: Please edit it to include a [mcve], and test data and expected hash. You might also want to look at the source code for Md5Hash in Java: [here](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/crypto/hash/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/crypto/hash/Md5Hash.java), and the super class [here](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/crypto/hash/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/crypto/hash/SimpleHash.java)

Comment: Why on earth would you want an MD5 for a password hash?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from reading the Java code [here](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/crypto/hash/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/crypto/hash/Md5Hash.java) and [here](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/crypto/hash/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/crypto/hash/SimpleHash.java), the difference is that it performs multiple iterations of the MD5 algorithm.

Taking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454004/calculate-a-md5-hash-from-a-string) and modifying it, I've reached this:

```
public static string CreateMD5(string input, string salt = null, int iterations = 1)
{
    // Use input string to calculate MD5 hash
    using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
    {
        byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

        // modification from linked answer: prefix with salt
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(salt) != null)
        {
            inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt).Concat(inputBytes).ToArray();
        }


        byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);



        // modification from linked answer: iterate N times
        for (int i = 1; i < iterations; ++i)
        {
            hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(hashBytes);
        }




        // Convert the byte array to hexadecimal string
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

public static string enPwd(string username, string pwd)
{
    return CreateMD5(username + pwd, username, 2);
}
```

As you can see, you just need to hash the resulting hash.

I've replicated what I saw in the Java library [here](https://rextester.com/OIXE89064), and the C# code produces the same result [here](https://rextester.com/FLBW65190).

Comment: Thanks, but the original code contains salt, how to add salt? I have tried hmacmd5 but not work.

Comment: I'm sorry. I missed that part. I'll check and get back to you :)

Comment: @Sven Please try now.

Comment: @Sven what does your Java code produce as a hash for username "john", password "test"? `85aa62decdd060986fcef7176291695e`, right?